# How to enable developer dashboard in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to enable developer dashboard in SharePoint 2013
I followed some tuts but it did not worked.

my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        //get dashboard setting objects
        SPDeveloperDashboardSettings dashboard_settings = SPWebService.ContentService.DeveloperDashboardSettings;

        dashboard_settings.DisplayLevel = SPDeveloperDashboardLevel.On;
        //---enable trace
        dashboard_settings.TraceEnabled = true;
        dashboard_settings.Update();
       }
   }
}
```

please if someone give a detailed example with sample codes and tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using PowerShell, and you also need the Usage and Health Data Collection enabled.

Check this: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html